# Adding text to a pdf?

Tags: java, python-3.x, pdf

So I have a template pdf for an agenda, what I want to know is how do I detect where the date should be.

Lets say in the template there is the word “DATE:”.

After that I want add the corresponding date/text next to that space so I detect “DATE:” and after writing it looks something like “DATE: 13/02/2020” and save it as a new pdf

Answer (score 0):

*You tagged your question both [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x). That makes it very broad. My answer, therefore, also is generic, not specific. In general you should decide which language you ask for.*

For your task you will need to do two things,

- first apply text extraction with coordinates to your pdf, search for that DATE marker in the text, and determine the coordinates right after that text piece; some libraries allow a shortcut and have routines that only extract text matching a regular expressions and its coordinates;
- then add text to your content at those coordinates.

Neither java nor python have explicit pdf support in their core. Thus, for your task you'll have to choose a pdf library for those tasks. (Theoretically you could try and implement your own pdf processing routines, but the pdf format is quite complex, so in general that would take very long.)

So you first should check which general purpose pdf library for your chosen language appears most appropriate for those tasks and your other requirements (like licensing). There are many questions and answers on stack overflow concerning text extraction which may help you in choosing.

---

Some words of warning, though, not all pdfs allow proper text extraction. There are pdf generators which don't add the information required for text extraction to pdfs; some actually even add misleading information. Thus, you might have to reject some templates. Alternatively, if the template is fixed, simply determine the correct coordinates for text insertion by measuring in a pdf viewer or by trial and error.

And if you still have influence on the requirements, propose to use templates with pdf AcroForm form fields. Form field fill-in allows more control for the template designer concerning the positioning and styling of the fill-ins, and fill-in is easier than the process outlined above. If you don't want form fields in the result pdfs, simply flatten the forms after fill-in.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for putting the languages since im not looking for one in specific but the purpose for that was to let users know that im open to any of those, maybe i should’ve done that in the text rather than in the tags, but thanks for the help